# Ng-repeat duplicates $index in select list EDIT: Ng Repeat doesn't load all values from list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

so im having this problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/0osQv9mnegqDdz5PzOvE?p=preview

I want when you press the button ADD that it displays A,B,C and not the same for every dropdown box.

```
<div ng-repeat="s in something">

<select ng-model="selected" style="color:black;width:5%;" ng-change="">

<option ng-repeat="n in characters" ng-selected="$index" >{{n}}</option>

</select>
</div>
```

as far as i know the SELECT tag has its own $scope and when you change it every other $index item is changed in that scope, how do i take the $parent.$index scope and make list bind to it so i get selected values based on the parent scope?

**EDIT**

found out this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fwwAd4bn6z2vxVN2FUL7?p=preview

when i do it like this it gets what i want, every dropdown has a seperate value, BUT it does not contain the others in the scope.

Comment: Your 'EDIT found out this:' plnkr.com link is the same as your problem.

Comment: Well i edited the same plnkr.. Press ADD and see what happens.. it should be ABC right now

Comment: @Carsten I edited it they are different now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by adding:

```
<option ng-repeat="n in characters" ng-selected="$parent.$index == $index" >{{n}}</option>
```